# Regex pattern to validate phone not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Just trying to create a simple Regex validation with JavaScript. I want to validate the phone number in the following format "+91-xxx-xxx-xxx", where the country code is fixed.

I have used the following regex pattern

```
/^[91]-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/
```

But it isn't working. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/Lwdt3hoh/2/)

Can you help?

Comment: Why would you impose that format on people, when in India mobile numbers are of the form +91 xxxxxxxxxx (10 digits), and fixed-line numbers are of the form +91 0xx yyyy-zzzz, but people put dashes and spaces in all different places anyway, or leave off the +91, so your regexp will almost never match?

Comment: Nope. Not imposing anything on anyone. Regex is new to me. I was just practising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `+` at the start and also you have to remove the character class which has `91`

```
^\+91-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oW1qN9/1)

This `[91]` would match a single character either, 9 or 1 but not `91`. To match `91`, you need to getout the number 91 from the character class. `+` is a meta character in regex, you need to escape it to match a literal `+` symbol.